# Which Neo4j Clojure library for embedded Neo4j?

Tags: clojure, neo4j

I want to use Neo4j with Clojure, but the official Neocons library does not support Neo4j in Embedded mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For embedded use, I believe https://github.com/wagjo/borneo is the most up-to-data implementation.